# how to print the value of an unicode string contained in a variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

I'm using python 2.7 and want to print the value of a field I receive on my server through a form.

I type `André` for the field `name`.

```
name = request.form['stripeBillingName']
```

How do I print the value of the variable `name` in a readable encoding?
I want to print `André` and not `Andr\xe9`

Comment: `print 'André'.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: I don't know the value of 'name' in advance. It is variable. That was just an example...

Comment: You can replace `'André'` with `name`. Anyway @MirzaS has summed it up beautifully.

Answer (score 3):

In source header you can declare

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
....
```

After that you can use utf-8, which should give you your desirable format

```
name = request.form['stripeBillingName']
nameDec = name.decode('utf8')
print nameDec
```

You can also encode it however you want e.g:

```
nameEnc = nameDec.encode('cp1250')
```

Comment: [Mon Aug 21 12:59:11.818743 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15356:tid 139986816960256] [client 192.168.159.241:53965]     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True), referer: https://www.dissectory.com/upgrade
[Mon Aug 21 12:59:11.818789 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 15356:tid 139986816960256] [client 192.168.159.241:53965] UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\\xe9' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: You can read up here about the error https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html, why it's caused and hope you find the solution for it. I may suggest you try encoding to different one, but I have no idea how your code looks like or where it throws the error. Also it seems like you're still using ascii codec.

Answer (score 0):

Use .decode("utf8")

Ex: "someUnicodeString".decode("utf8")